# Why can't I read file after my for loops python using ubuntu

Tags: python, printing, for-loop, readfile

For some reason after my for loops I am not able to read the ouput text file.
For example :

```
for line in a:
 name = (x)
 f = open('name','w')
for line in b:
 get = (something)
 f.write(get)
for line in c:
 get2 = (something2)
 f.write(get2)

 (the below works if the above is commented out only)

f1 = open(name, 'r')
for line in f1:
 print line
```

If I comment out the loops, I am able to read the file and print the contents.

I am very new to coding and guessing this is something obvious that I am missing.However I can't seem to figure it out. I have used google but the more I read the more I feel I am missing something. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: make sure you `.close()` the file after you're done writing. better yet: use a context manager (`with` statement) which closes the file for you at the conclusion of the `with` block; plus exceptions are handled for free

Comment: At the very least, you will need to flush the file you're writing to.

Comment: Are you sure you've pasted in your code correctly? Your `f = open('name', 'w')` line is happening inside a for loop, so it'll be reassigned every time you go through the loop, and you'll just end up with whatever f was on the last run through the loop.

Comment: Agreed, are you perhaps trying to open and write to multiple files? Otherwise I can't for the life of me think what the name variable is for.

Comment: The string `'name'` is not the same as the variable `name`

Answer (score 3):

@bernie is right in his comment above. The problem is that when you do `open(..., 'w')`, the file is rewritten to be blank, but Python/the OS doesn't actually write out the things you `write` to disk until its buffer is filled up or you call `close()`. (This delay helps speed things up, because writing to disk is slow.) You can also call `flush()` to force this without closing the file.

The `with` statement bernie referred to would look like this:

```
 with open('name', 'w') as f:
     for line in b:
         b.write(...)
     for line in c:
         b.write(...)
 # f is closed now that we're leaving the with block
 # and any writes are actually written out to the file

 with open('name', 'r') as f:
     for line in f:
         print line
```

If you're using Python 2.5 rather than 2.6 or 2.7, you'll have to do `from __future__ import with_statement` at the top of your file.

Comment: It looks to be the fact I was not closing the file. 
Marius- you are correct I copied that wrong. I was actually using name to create the filename for the output from inside a XML file that changes all the time. I know better ways are out there but I just don’t know them yet.
Thank you all for your help it is much appreciated.

Comment: would it be better to go with a with than the for loop in this case? What would be considered better coding?

Comment: `with` is better for the reasons Bernie cited, but it doesn't allow you to drop the `for` loop at all.